Add a Text box above the SharePoint list which can be updated inline
Is it possible to add a text box at the top of the SharePoint list with a slightly offset background color which can be edited inline?
This needs to be added right below the List name if possible. The whole intention is to show a notification to the users on how to update the list

This is specifically a Sharepoint question, perhaps better asked at Sharepoint SE

There is no out-of-the-box way for SharePoint to do this. Maybe you can try SPFx with a development solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview
